# How would I use getopt for this?

Tags: c++, c, getopt

I am in need of a way to parse multiple switches that come out as a single argument ( argv ), some of the switches in my program would be, for example:

```
-rRsc
```

How would I implement getopt so that the user can enter multiple switches all as one argument, no spaces or dashes between switches, so no:

```
-r -R -s -c
```

Or is this not possible to be done with getopt? If it isnt, what else can I use that is part of the STL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getopt already handles this case by default. You don't need to do anything special. (Scroll down to the end of [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt) to see an example.)

Comment: What if the functionality of a switch is dependent on a switch before it? So for -r, if -c is on as well its a recursive file scan of C++ file extensions only. So how would I put these options in? Nested switch/if statement?

Comment: @AaronG. No. Mintain a list of Boolean flags.

Answer (score 0):

you should know `-rRsc` is equal to `-r -R -s -c`.

Comment: @AaronG. And this answer doesn't imply that you should specify them in the format you don't want either.